# JS - Count characters of each array words

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I need to write down for an array list the array and then the number of characters that array consists of.

example

```
apple 5 
banana 6
grapefruit 10
```

I have trouble to count the characters of one array.
I only know to count the list of arrays, ie. in this example 3.

It needs to be a loop.

So for now I have this

```js
const fruit = ["apple", "banana", "grapefruit"];

let fruitCountChar = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {
  fruitCountChar = fruit.length;
  console.log(fruit[i], fruitCountChar);
}
```

Comment: change `fruitCountChar = fruit.length;` to `fruitCountChar = fruit[i].length;`. You are counting the items in whole array.

Comment: All these downvotes - the OP even says themselves they are a beginner. Just because it's a simple issue doesn't mean it doesn't deserver an answer. If you don't know the problem then how do you know what to research in order to solve it? No wonder this place has a dreadful reputation these days. Honestly.

Comment: Using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) based callback makes a possible solution as easy as this ... `['apple', 'banana', 'grapefruit'].forEach(fruitName => console.log(fruitName, fruitName.length));`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already managed to successfully log the fruit *names* to console, all you need to do now, is access the `length` property of *the exact same thing*:

```js
const fruit = ["apple", "banana", "grapefruit"];

let fruitCountChar = 0;    
   for (let i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {    
      fruitCountChar = fruit[i].length;
                         // ^^^
      console.log(fruit[i], fruitCountChar);
}
```